# How can I store multiple items in an json array without duplicates?

Tags: python, arrays, json, twisted

I'm trying to develop some kind of peer-to-peer system in python. When a client connects to my server, the client sends all files inside a specific location. When a client sends data to the server, it does this via json. When the server gets information from the client, it will then print it. An example:

```
{
    "Localfiles": [{
        "IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],
        "FileLength": 363031,
        "FileName": "chromeicon.png"
    }, {
        "IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],
        "FileLength": 363031,
        "FileName": "chromeicon.png"
    }]
}
```

This is what it prints when the client sends information about a location twice(a folder with only 1 file). how can I make it so that when i append data to my json array, that it won't show up as duplicate.

Here's my code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
import os, json

data = {}  
data['Localfiles'] = []
def test(datas):
    test = json.loads(datas)
    for x in range(0,(len(test['Localfiles']))):
        if x not in data:
            data['Localfiles'].append({
                'FileName':test['Localfiles'][x]['FileName'],
                'FileLength':test['Localfiles'][x]['FileLength'],
                'IPAddress':test['Localfiles'][x]['IPAddress']
            })

    print json.dumps(data) +"\n"
    return data

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        try:
            self.transport.write(json.dumps(test(data)))                  
        except ValueError:
            print "nope"

def main():
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = Echo
    reactor.listenTCP(5000,factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about collapsing the dictionary once you have iterated over the values:

```
import json
dic = '{"Localfiles":[{"IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],"FileLength": 363031,"FileName": "chromeicon.png"},{"IPAddress": ["217.120.103.158"],"FileLength": 363031,"FileName":"chromeicon.png"}]}'

data = {}  
data["Localfiles"] = []
def test(datas):
    test = json.loads(str(datas))
    for x in range(0,(len(test["Localfiles"]))):
        if x not in data:
            data["Localfiles"].append({
                "FileName":test["Localfiles"][x]["FileName"],
                "FileLength":test["Localfiles"][x]["FileLength"],
                "IPAddress":test["Localfiles"][x]["IPAddress"]
            })

    L = data["Localfiles"]
    data["Localfiles"] = list({v['FileName']:v for v in L}.values())

    return data
```

This gives me:

```
{'Localfiles': [{'FileLength': 363031,
   'FileName': 'chromeicon.png',
   'IPAddress': ['217.120.103.158']}]}
```

Comment: "the client sends all files inside a specific location" .. what do you mean by files ? binary images or images descriptors ?
what do you want really achieve ? .. retrieving images hosted from your clients ?

Comment: When a client connects to my server, it sends the contents of a specific location to my server in the form of json(filename, filesize and IP address from client. Everytime a client connects to my server, the server sends back everything that gets added by the clients. When 2 clients are connected, the clients can download stuff from another client.